# Today function equivalent in VBA in combination with countifs

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some problem with using a  countifs formula in Excel / VBA. I have got the formula working perfect in Excel but ideally I want to use this in VBA with my form. Here is the formula in Excel which works a treat:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,"Place",Sheet1!K:K,"<"&TODAY())
```

will count the names places that are now in the past

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,"place",Sheet1!K:K,">"&TODAY())
```

will count the names places that are current

I have five different Places in column A and hundreds of different dates in column K. The above formulas work well in Excel and return the correct values. I have spent hours trying to get this to work in VBA with my userform but keep getting various errors. The first part is not the problem but as soon as I get to the &today function it falls apart. From what I can see the &today function is not available in VBA and the &Date seems to be the recommendation. I have tried this but still get no where. I'm missing a trick (or several) here and I would really like to get this working in VBA rather than using the current formulas in Excel. The returned results are then displayed in textboxes on my form.

All ideas and feedback much welcome!

Second edit

================================

Thanks for the quick replies! Here is the actual code I am playing about with in VBA

```
 'Count events by area'
Dim ListLondon As Long

ListLondon = .CountIf(Range("a1:a1998"), "London"), ("Sheet1!K1:K1998"), "<" & Date)

End With

Me.TextBox1 = ListLondon
```

I know the second part of the count if is all wrong regards the date - that's how I've left it for now. I am really hoping to use the current layout and a working Date / Today code at the end. Please show me what I've done wrong here!

====

oops - can see a mistake already - but the initial problem remains around the date issue. I should of used countifs as using multiple criteria.

Comment: Can we see the code you are trying?  It may be how you entered.  Try [Date()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/date_vba.php)

Comment: You will need to put your code in your original post, using the "edit" link.

Comment: Try: `ListLondon = WorkSheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a1998"), "London", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1:K1998"), "<" & Date)`

Comment: I have tried that code and am getting the following error:complier error:

Can't find project or library. Thanks for your help so far on this!

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot the `s`: `listlondon = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a1998"), "London", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1:K1998"), "<" & Date)`

Comment: Mmm. I've google'd the error and it refers to a reference that appears to be mising on my PC. So the chances are your code is spot on - but I will not be able to fully test it until tomorrow on my work pc. Seem to be missing refedit.dll - or at least thats what is highlighted under references.

Comment: There must be something more to the code than the lines provided.  Because using excel - vba there is nothing that should throw that error.  One question though, are you using a Mac?  You may need to change the `Sheets(...)` with `worksheets(...)`

Comment: I also checked out that article regards Mac version of Excel. I am using Windows 7 with Excel 2007. I will have a look at the renaming of the sheets

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to read the values of the cells to your VBA code. I recommend you to use Excel.Range object to do that. It can interpret the range like the edit line of the Excel, something like

   Dim foo as Excel.Range

   set foo = yourworksheet.Range("A1:B3")
2. Read the Date type data into VBA Date type variable by iterating through the cells.
3. Examine relation between the read data and the current date. Current date can be read by using the *DateTime.Now* function.
4. Increment a variable based on a decision

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! Here is the actual code I am playing about with in VBA: